# Autohotkeys GUI. How to have multiple controls with same name

Tags: autohotkey

Is it possible to have multiple controls in a gui of autohotkeys to have the same name. Like in a GUI I have two buttons with the name Browse. How do I do that.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you click on the white check mark next to FakeRainBrigand's answer, to mark that as the best answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom action for a control with a [g-label](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Events).  Here's an example where two browse buttons have different actions.

```
Gui, Add, Button, gFirstBrowse, Browse
Gui, Add, Button, gSecondBrowse, Browse
Gui, Show
return

FirstBrowse:
MsgBox % "You pressed the first browse button!"
return

SecondBrowse:
MsgBox % "You pressed the second browse button!"
return
```

Comment: Great Answer. I expected that there were better ways since there are often several roads that lead to Rome (and yours is a highway!).

Comment: This is perfect. But the problem with this is "How do I have g-label as well as coordinates and dimensions for a button.. If I put the g-lable before the coordinates like this -
"Gui, Add, Button, x292 y50 w100 h30, gb1, Browse"
the lable becomes 
"gb1, Browser"
if I put the g-lable before the coordinates like this.. 
"Gui, Add, Button, gb1, x292 y50 w100 h30, Browse"
the display on the button in the GUI becomes "x292 y50 w100 h30, Browse".. any help on this..? The documentation of the GUI in the help file is not that elaborate so sorry for asking too many questions :P.

Comment: @user2243609, All of your options go in the same parameter.  There shouldn't be a comma between the sizing and the glabel.  `Gui, Add, Button, x292 y50 w100 h30 gb1, Browse`

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the add button with the same name, but different coordinates

```
Gui, Add, Button, x10  y275 w45 h20, Paste
Gui, Add, Button, x60  y275 w45 h20, Paste
```

Will show two similar buttons, that will both trigger the same label `ButtonPaste:`

If you want two buttons with the same text but different behaviour, you could try to use the mouse coordinates to decide the actual behaviour.

```
ButtonPaste:
MouseGetPos, By, Bx
If By between 10 and 55
{
    ;Clicked Paste Button 1
}
Else
{
    ;Clicked Paste Button 2
}
```

Comment: But is it possible to define different name for them so that I can have them trigger with different events..?

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you anymore. Please define clearly what it is you want. Do you want the same button text BUT different behaviour?

Comment: Thanks. your answer clearly explains it now. This is what I wanted.. I thought autohotkey would have handeled this situation better... nonetheless the thing you specified will get the job done.

Comment: It still could be that there are other ways to do the same. I just provided a way to do this. If you like my answer, could you click the white check mark next to the answer. This way my answer is accepted as the best answer. Regards.